# Using Generics to find fragment in childFragmentManager using "is" not useable?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I'm trying to restore a fragment in my ViewPager on rotate to resolve some issues, and wrote some code that works perfectly when used normally, but when I try to make it a generic function to reuse it, it's not working.

Whatever I try to do in the `childFragmentManager.fragments.find` lambda using my passed in parameter remains red and unuseable when trying to do an IS check.

Working Code

```
val studySurveyFragment = if (restoring) {
            val fragment = childFragmentManager.fragments.find { it is StudySurveyFragment }
            if (fragment == null) {
                StudySurveyFragment()
            } else {
                fragment as StudySurveyFragment
            }
        } else {
            StudySurveyFragment()
        }
```

My attempt at a generic version

```
create(StudySurveyFragment(), StudySurveyFragment::class.java)

fun <T> create(fragment: Fragment, fragmentClass: Class<T>): Fragment {
        return if (restoring) {
            val findFragment = childFragmentManager.fragments.find { it is fragmentClass }
            if (findFragment == null) {
                fragment
            } else {
                findFragment
            }
        } else {
            fragment
        }
    }
```

Update: I've tried doing this as well, which will compile, but the check doesn't actually work

```
childFragmentManager.fragments.find {it.javaClass.isInstance(fragmentClass)}
```

Note: I know this can be reduced with some elvis operators, but I was trying to make it work as expected first...

Comment: I don't think you should be calling fragments. Isn't that a restricted API?

Comment: Your is-check is wrong. You're asking if the class IS a Class<Something>, not if it's a Something. Consider using an inline reified function instead, and then you won't even need to pass the class reference.

Comment: What you suggested works, bu I still had to pass the class reference to be able to instantiate it on the else?  If you write an answer for it I can mark it.    inline fun <reified T> FragmentManager.findOrCreateFragment(clazz: Class<T>): T? {
        return this.fragments.find { it is T } as T? ?: clazz.newInstance()
    }

Comment: The API isn't restricted either, it's just me calling the child fragment manager.  I need to same fragment to re-attach my presenter otherwise it's null.

Comment: Also just realized I don't need the return T? can be return T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> FragmentManager.findOrCreateFragment(): T {
    return fragments.find { it is T } as T? ?: T::class.java.newInstance()
}
```

No need to pass a class reference.

PS: I'm pretty sure that `fragmentManager.getFragments()` (or, in Kotlin, `fragmentManager.fragments`) *used to be* a restricted API, but you're right, it doesn't appear to be so anymore.

Comment: shouldn't `findOrCreate` return a Non-Null value? When `find` method returns null we create a new instance either way.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I was just thoughtlessly preserving your original method signature.

Comment: Oh, it's also worth noting you could have used the safe-cast operator `as?`

Comment: Oh sweet!  You got rid of the need to pass the class in like I thought I had to.!  Thanks for cleaning that up even more and letting me know what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I could do this without generics... but after further consideration, using generics where I could go clazz.newInstance() instead of having to create the class to check would be more efficient, so if there's a way to do that I'd much prefer it.

```
fun create(fragment: Fragment): Fragment {
        return if (restoring) {
            val findFragment =
                childFragmentManager.fragments.find { it.javaClass.isInstance(fragment) }
            if (findFragment == null) {
                fragment
            } else {
                findFragment
            }
        } else {
            fragment
        }
    }
```

Can be shortened to this, also realized if it's not restoring, they'll be null anyway...

```
fun findOrCreate(fragment: Fragment): Fragment {
     return childFragmentManager.fragments.find { it.javaClass.isInstance(fragment) } ?: fragment
}
```